# Flutter save application to phone memory

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I want to save the application I made in Flutter to the phone's memory and when I close the application and open it again, I want it to continue from where it left off. How can I do this?

I tried the sharedpreferences library but it wasn't a good solution for my application.

In my project, there is a button positioned by the user, and these button positions are kept in the List array. Apart from that, there is an area where he can draw on the same page. I want to save this button position and the drawings.

Comment: Why sharedpreferences wasn't a good solution for your application? explain more details.

Comment: Yes agree with @amir_a14. Would like to know what kind of data (model) are you trying to save to phone's memory

Comment: have you use any database like hive,sqlite

Comment: Sharedpreferences is good to work with phone's memory, Maybe the asynchronous of Sharedpreferences make you some hard to use it. You can try the SQLite, but i think sharedpreferences better in almost case.

Comment: because I was able to save single data with shared preferences, I couldn't save the whole application and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: You can store new screen name every time a new screen opens in a shared preference, in that way you will be able to see which screen was opened last time and then move user forward accordingly. You will need to write code in Splash screen to check which screen was opened last.

Answer (score 0):

Use file storage to save the application state. You can use the [`path_provider`](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) package in Flutter to get access to the file system. You can save the application data in a file and read it when the application starts up again.

Comment: Is the only alternative path provider?

Answer (score 0):

if you are doing state management with GetX then you should refer to this package [get_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/get_storage) , currently my project is still using it to store in phone memory.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: In my project, there is a button positioned by the user, and these button positions are kept in the List<ButtonData> array. Apart from that, there is an area where he can draw on the same page. I want to save this button position and the drawings.